# How to redirect user to third party website via intermediate website

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce

I am setting up the payment method on a website (website A) via submission of a form. The goal is to pass the information from website A via an intermediary website (website B), then through to the payment gateway.

My question is, how do I redirect the user from website A through website B which "activates" the javascript code without any action from the user, which then redirects the user to the payment gateway page as the final page for payment?

The code to redirect the user to the payment gateway I need "activated" on website B is in Javascript. An example is:

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  items: [
    // Replace with the ID of your SKU
    {sku: 'sku_123', quantity: 1}
  ],
  successUrl: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancelUrl: 'https://example.com/cancel',
}).then(function (result) {
});
```

Website B also runs on Wordpress and will have the required gateway script in the 'wp-head'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using one of their “Elements” to gather the payment info in your form on site A? Those render inside an iframe, with the content loaded from their servers - so you have no access to that data using your own scripting. I don’t think what you want is possible using their client-side SDK, it is not meant for stuff like this.

Comment: (And apart from that, I would question the intended flow here to begin with. Being redirected via an “intermediate” site, when a site wants me to pay for something, might not increase my feeling that this is a secure process to begin with, but rather the opposite …)

Comment: The customer's info will be gathered using a forms plugin which will then be sent with the rest of the script to website B.